# Assign var with elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay, so i have this array that's taken from Google sheets.

[image]

Now I want to assign variables with the elements from this array.
I have a function that creates a timer that needs to take the Title,Date,Image
how do I loop through the array and assign the temp variables then execute the function. and keep going until it goes through all the rows, so for this one it would have 4 timers.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Did you search on SO before asking this question?

Comment: Yes, I did, I spent hours searching but I'm still learning so perhaps I didn't use the correct terms/keywords and it kept leading me to different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to iterate through the array, but [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is most likely the easiest:

```
arrayOfItems.forEach(item => {
    let title = item[0];
    let date = item[1];
    let image = item[2];
    executeFunction(title, date, image);
});
```

With new es6 [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you could also write it as:

```
arrayOfItems.forEach(([title, date, image]) => {
    executeFunction(title, date, image);
});
```

Comment: You could also do: `forEach(([title, date, image]) => { … })`

Comment: I spent hours trying to do this, this worked. I kept trying to do it in a more complex way, glad I asked.

Comment: @Li357 I updated my answer to include that. I keep forgetting about the new snazzy es6 functions